# Gerando PDF de uma página da Web com o Phantom

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Estou desenvolvendo no Node uma aplicação onde tenho uma página html, que preencho com dados do banco e depois preciso salvar esta página em PDF. Estou tentando usar o Phatom, já tentei seguir vários tutoriais, mas quando eu passo o URL da página ele salva o PDF diversas vezes, ele não termina o processo e sempre sobrescreve o PDF gerado. O que posso fazer para resolver isso?

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function() {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1024 });

    const status = await page.open('http://localhost/gerar_diploma?id_aluno='+_id);

    console.time('wait');

    await timeout(500);

    console.timeEnd('wait');

    await page.render('docs/result.pdf');

    await instance.exit();
})();
```

Comment: Boa tarde, se você seguir a documentação e recriar este [Exemplo](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/blob/master/examples/render.js) seu pdf sera criado com sucesso. Os metodos do phantom são promessas, não tem a necessidade de criar um contador para retornar as promessas.

Answer (score 0):

Caso tenha dificuldade aqui esta o método, caso queria é só exportar o metodo `createPDF` e importar e passar a url por parâmetro.

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

async function createPDF(url) {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();

  await page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1600, height: 900 });
  const status = await page.open(url);
  console.log(`Page opened with status [${status}].`);
  await page.render(new Date().getTime()+'-'+'newPDF.pdf');
  await instance.exit();
};


createPDF('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348094/gerando-pdf-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina-da-web-com-o-phantom')
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, o código que você mostrou funciona para qualquer url que eu passar, exceto para uma url da aplicação, a pagina que eu gostaria de salvar está em uma url do tipo: http://localhost/gerar_diploma?id_aluno=5c03314741550317208e0784, quando eu passo esse endereço o problema persiste e ele sai gerando sucessivos arquivos pdf..

Comment: Boa noite, o conteúdo desse pdf é a pagina? Essa pagina esta em uma url protegida ou algo do tipo? Poderia dar detalhes da pagina. Eu fiz alguns teste com url semelhante a sua e obtive sucesso.